# WP8 Runtime - How to bind content to email in code behind C#?

Tags: c#, email, data-binding, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I haven't found an answer for this so far. I have a WP8 Runtime app with this code behind on my detail page to send an email from the app:

```
        private async void Email_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create your new email message.
        var em = new EmailMessage();

        // Add as much EmailRecipient in it as you need using the following method.
        //em.To.Add(new EmailRecipient("yourname@yourdomain.com"));
        em.Subject = "{Binding Description}";
        em.Body = "Your email body...";
        // You can add an attachment that way.
        //em.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(...);

        // Show the email composer.
        await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(em);
    }
```

My question is how do I go about using a binding from my detail page for the Subject and Body? This way the email from each detail page will have different email content.

Comment: In the context of your sample code, you want to bind the `em.Body` and `em.Subject` to what?

Comment: I want to bind to my datamodel - to the content that is displayed on each detail page.

Comment: If it's code behind, you just need to get the text from the control of your page... so em.Subject = SubjectTextBox.Text

Comment: em.Subject = SubjectTextBox is not working for me on WP8 Runtime